# As validatePassword () receives the user's password?

Tags: validation, yii2

As `validatePassword()` receives the user's password?

I not know how `validatePassword()` get password user.

`$password` - Getting here is assigned to the user's password?

```
<?php 
namespace app\models;  

class User extends \yii\base\Object implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        Yii::info('Пароль validateAuthKey ----'.$authKey);
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe code you show is the User.php model code in basic template application.
 as you can see in site controller  the action login call $model->login()

```
 public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) { // *** here
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

($model  is obtained by new LoginForm();).

in $model->login (alias in LoginForm->login()) you have this code

```
 /**
 * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
 * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
 */
public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    }
    return false;
}
```

this code perform the login